# How do I split an object file with only numerical information

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a file (supplied to me) with information regarding polygons. The file shown below has an introductory line for each polygon, giving a polygon number (increasing by one each time), a polygon type, a material type and a polygon shape index. This is followed by the vertex coordinates for the polygon. This is repeated for thousands of polygons.

I am trying to split the file into each polygon, however, the only thing I can think to split each polygon is the polygon number. I have created a list in the range of polygon numbers (1-max polygon numbers) and have tried several loops to separate the introductory line for each polygon (so I can use it for splitting the file)

Part of my problem appears to be that I have an object file (strings). I have so far used readlines to read in the file and in order to print the first polygon number, I use print(lines[1][0]), with the polygon number being the first entry on the second line.

Ive included a copy of the file being read below with some annotation. Not all polygons have the same amount of vertices (and hence not the same number of rows) as this is dependent on the polygon index. I apologise that the question is a little vague as I found it difficult to summarize. Im also relatively new to python, so any pointers are always appreciated.

```
1,1,29    (# of polygon, # of material, # of polygon type in library file)
0.5277962740910911,1.0456819526290850,1.0948605296487677     (x,y,z coordinate of each vertex)
0.5011598934085548,1.0395150263236856,1.0653193210482526
0.4903338672248754,1.0771309246663361,1.0489463087366191
0.5156720928270351,1.1097455445706370,1.0741368888234422
0.5199725323381347,1.0907793308059559,1.0451826388198324
0.5581768869702011,1.0934823937812110,1.0771768507752582
0.5766900359882420,1.0673139704744661,1.0462587295599690
0.5642355660780601,1.0603056770177570,1.0735771052222927
0.5103687290213037,1.0438567955893303,1.0534979253843588
0.5436066285899484,1.0894647772771411,1.1080287259376500
2,1,11
0.6094172444555466,1.9390929511037345,1.0979723438943572
0.6084893664951661,1.9387519298419549,1.1262860530324115
0.6252289018994945,1.9160130726011515,1.1360101624226611
0.6375226652185119,1.9012706382225484,1.1078872575138881
0.6443130026409927,1.9191035856647312,1.1233324562878342
0.6476870913145844,1.9250628296791572,1.0888812278496522
0.6584630641731621,1.9524225282729630,1.0997401873141526
0.6390921704088826,1.9471816364084147,1.0914827275094192
0.6189550003509075,1.9415920286827033,1.1280131484814933
0.6270846578202443,1.9166951151247156,1.0793827441465607
3,1,30
0.3258097456956404,1.0787387490292795,1.1356703268819104
0.3112589748010373,1.0845879190127123,1.1585442149630210
0.3184515384997510,1.1114872393118218,1.1674496886902679
0.3410308564940696,1.1222711339565852,1.1454296968527427
0.3171314615574631,1.1228000066147681,1.1478932170242970
0.3299250228505521,1.1148638859087066,1.1169796858851651
0.2999923174788897,1.1130461281963779,1.1104742092188233
0.3141994943374792,1.0977633978672907,1.1144529527957583
0.3050337749145687,1.0922180321814965,1.1542342796564746
0.3475530802889496,1.0997888993449492,1.1217019125280410
```

Comment: In case you'd ever be willing to use R, there is a very easy solution available.

Comment: Sorry, i have no time for a comprehensive answer now. But you should try to narrow down, what a description line and what a coordinates line is composed of and translate it to regular expression, which you can use to split file into polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is **always** a row of 3 integers followed by 10 rows of 3 floats the below will work.

```py
#Open file and create a list of each line of data
with open('/path/to/file','r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

#create a dictionary to hold the data
polygonData = {}

#iterate over the loaded data
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if i % 11 == 0:
        numbers = d.split(',') #Split line 0, 11, 22 at the commas
        ID = tuple(int(n) for n in numbers) #Create a tuple of integers from the numbers
        polygonData[ID] = [] #Add an element to the dictionary with an empty list
    else:
        numbers = d.split(',') #Split lines other than 0, 11, 22 at the commas
        vertices = [float(n) for n in numbers] #Create a list of floats from those numbers
        polygonData[ID].append(vertices) #Append to the list corresponding to the most recent ID
```

Each `key` in polygonData is now a `tuple` identifying the polygon number, polygon material and polygon type.  The corresponding `value` is a list where each element of the list is the (x, y, z) for each vertex of the polygon.

EDIT:

Assuming the file **always** starts with 3 integers the identifiers are **always** integers and the vertices are **always** floats:

```py
with open('/path/to/file','r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

#create a dictionary to hold the data
polygonData = {}


for i, d in enumerate(data):
    splitLine = d.split(',')
    if '.' not in splitLine[0]:
        newID = tuple(int(s) for s in splitLine)
        polygonData[newID] = []
    else:
        newValue = [float(s) for s in splitLine]
        polygonData[newID].append(newValue)
```

polygonData is the same as before, but now accepts arbitrary numbers of vertices.

Comment: Apologies, unfortunately, it is not always 10 rows of floats, this depends on the polygon index. Ill update my question to include this information now

Comment: @MattC1990 That makes it harder...  Is it possible to add something at the start/end of each polygon identifier to indicate that it's the start of a new polygon?  Perhaps a string so it becomes "START,1,1,29"?

Comment: Im actually not sure, as this file has been supplied to me (i.e im not the person creating it), Im currently investigating reading this is a .csv to see if that helps

Comment: Ah ok.  Is it always integers for the identifier and always floats for the vertices?

Comment: Right now, everything is string, and I cant convert to float because of commas (I think) thats why if looking at csv

Comment: I mean, is it that the identifier will **never** have a decimal point, and the vertices will **always** have a decimal point?

Comment: 2nd version should suffice.